Why generalized eigenvectors give the Jordan normal form.
Given a matrix $A$ over a field $k$, let $P$ be the generalized modal matrix of $A$(see here for definition) consists of generalized eigenvectors of $A$. I am trying to prove that $AP=PJ$ where $J$ is the Jordan normal form of $A$.
For the following I write a vector to mean a column.
Basically the generalized modal matrix $P$ is of the form $$P=\begin{bmatrix}v_1 &v_2&\dots& v_n\end{bmatrix}$$for generalized eigenvectors $v_i$ of $A$ with a certain rule of order. So one really need to prove that $$\begin{bmatrix}Av_1 &Av_2&\dots& Av_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}Pw_1 &Pw_2&\dots& Pw_n\end{bmatrix}$$where $w_i$ are the rows of $J$, or that $$Av_i=Pw_i.$$I think I am not doing this right. Is there anyway I can work with linear operators, regarding $A$ as a matrix of some linear operator $T$ with respect to some basis and then give an easier proof?

first work sseparatedly on each block of J, then remember the definition of generalized eigenvectors
